# setInterval argumet is undefined in the second function call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm generating a file from an API, and need to keep making a request until the file is ready,so I used the setInterval to invoke the ajax call repeatedly but in the second call the URL becomes undefined.

```
$( "#campaign-list-table form").submit(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        let exportOption = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
        let postUrl = $(this).attr('action');

        setInterval(ajaxd(postUrl), 5000);

    });

    /**
     *
     * @param postUrl
     */
    let ajaxd = function (postUrl) {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: postUrl,
            contentType: "application/xml",
            complete: function (data) {

                //let $xmlObject = parseXML(data);
                console.log(postUrl);
                    ajaxd();

            }
        });
    }
```

I expect the output of the URL to be 'api/export/2988475 , but the second output is undefined.

Comment: Why don't you pass `postUrl` as argument to your function call?

Comment: just pass the `postUrl` to `ajaxd();`

Comment: Why at all a `setInterval` when you call the function again after the previous one has success?

Comment: @ trincot i don't know how i didn't pay attention to it, thank you , it works now

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing a function to `setInterval`, but rather calling the function `ajaxd` and passing its result as the first argument to `setInterval`.

Wrap your call to `ajaxd` in an anonymous function:

```
setInterval(function () {
    ajaxd(postUrl)
}, 5000);
```

Comment: This won't change the `ajaxd()` call in the `complete` handler (but this call doesn't make much sense anyway / or the `setInterval`...)

Comment: still getting undefined inside the anonymous function.
@sdgluck why isnt making sense ?

Comment: @TarekHatem all I can say is that you *shouldn't* be getting that. Although if you're running literally the code posted, then you have a line that is simply ` ajaxd();` - you are **not** passing an argument there, so in that invocation `postingUrl` would be `undefined`.

Comment: @sdgluck definetly right, i don't know how i didn't pay attention to it , thank you for the fast response.